# Call Permalink in Wordpress Counter

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a code i found in the Internet to count Facebook shares, but I'm not able to call the permalink I'm using.

The function:

```
<?php
$facebook_like_share_count = function ( $url ) {

    $api = file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $url );

    $count = json_decode( $api );

    return $count->shares;
};
?>
```

The call:

```
<?php echo $facebook_like_share_count( 'http://www.someurl.com' ); ?>
```

My permalink:

```
<?php the_job_permalink(); ?>
```

I tried many ways and none worked.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm calling inside the loop.

Comment: where is the_job_permalink() defined?

Comment: I suppose here https://github.com/mikejolley/WP-Job-Manager/blob/master/wp-job-manager-template.php